# How to get url from video playing in webview using javascript?

Tags: javascript, c#, windows, video, webview

I am developing a UWP app, and I want to get a video url using from a webview. I want a button to appear when I play the video on fullscreen (I managed to do that) and then, when I click the button, I need to extract the video url somehow. 
I have this, but I am afraid this will not get an url, and also, there might be other videos on the page, so I am not sure if it will get the one I am currently playing in fullscreen.

```
var value = await Browser.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[] {
    "document.getElementById('video')" 
});
```